# Catch 403 from Fetch without Console Error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch, http-status-code-403, sentry

I'm trying to fetch a file from S3 if there is a file at the given `src` url, and if not have a handled fallback. The logic works fine, but I'm looking for a way to prevent the `403` error from appearing in the console so as to prevent triggering Sentry and leaving error codes in the user's console.

```
const res = await fetch(src)
if (res.ok) obj[key] = await res.json()
else obj[key] = defaultValue
```

Essentially I'm looking for the effect of a `try/catch`, but an actual `try/catch` does not prevent the network error from being logged. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent Sentry from triggering, or from logging the 403 in the console?

Comment: I have a built in fallback - in other words, a 200 and a 403 are both expected cases, the 403 is simply a legacy db instance that is handled separately. It does not in this case warrant throwing an error.

Comment: OK. Why specifically don't you want Sentry triggering or the console logging out your 403? Can you not filter out your 403s in Sentry? Is logging the 403 to the console harmful to your clients? Why exactly don't you want this default behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent the call from being logged in the network tab in the browser. This is default behavior of the browser.